# Plot a multi bar graph on the same axes with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib` and python 3.7 to plot an expense report divided into categories.

The goal would be to plot a multi-bar graph to compare data year over year.

I found a way to do this using a line graph, but not with the more appropriate bar graph because the bar just overlap each other.
[image]

This is the code used to generate this graph:

```
data = {'category 1': 120.50,
        'category 2': 135.59,
        'category 3': 130.71,
        'category 4': 150.71}
group_data = list(data.values())
group_names = list(data.keys())

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)
axs[0].plot(group_names, group_data, label="2020")
axs[0].plot(group_names, [v * 1.1 for v in group_data], label="2019")

axs[1].bar(group_names, group_data, label="2020")
axs[1].bar(group_names, [v * 1.1 for v in group_data], label="2019")


axs[0].legend()
```

Looked at the official doc (https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html) but didn't find a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider Pandas for easy plot function:

```
import pandas as pd

# 2020 data
df = pd.DataFrame({'2020':data})

# 2019 data
df['2019'] = df['2020'] * 1.1

# plot bar
df.plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, quick and easy solution. Do you know if I can still access to the underlying axes to customize the look and feel of this graph?

Comment: @IgnazioC yes, `ax = df.plot.bar()`, then `ax` is an axis instance. You can also pass a predefined axis to `bar`: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(); df.plot.bar(ax=ax)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `zorder` to decide the stack order of your bars. The ***bars with smaller height should have a higher z-order*** so that they appear at the front.

```
axs[1].bar(group_names, group_data, label="2020", zorder=1)
axs[1].bar(group_names, [v * 1.1 for v in group_data], label="2019", zorder=0)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but I think this would only work if the second bar has higher values than the first one. That's true in my example but I cannot ensure this for real data.

Comment: @IgnazioC Yes, you are right. The other solution is the best workaround in that case.